# Lograr que un UIImageview ocupe toda la pantalla

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy trabajando con TableViewControllers y en mi primer TableView he decidido que me aparezca una imagen que me ocupe todo el largo y ancho de la pantalla de  tal manera que no se vea lo que hay detras si no hasta que la imagen desaparezca (Esta parte ya esta lograda). Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav!.hidden = true
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenHeight = bounds.size.height
    let screenWidth = bounds.size.width
   

    let dynamicImage=UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight))
    dynamicImage.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    
    self.view.addSubview(dynamicImage)
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 10.0, options: [] , animations: {() -> Void in
        dynamicImage.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {(true) -> Void in
            dynamicImage.removeFromSuperview()
            nav!.hidden = false
    })
```

El caso es que la pantalla me queda asi:

[image: Captura de pantalla]

y no me ocupa todo el alto de la pantalla, puesto que aun se ve la barra superior, ademas de que si toco la pantalla y deslizo hacia arriba se desplaza el scroll recorriendo el UIImageview hacia arriba. Lo que pretendo es que el UIImageview contenga un imagen publicitaria que dure x cantidad d segundos con la pantalla bloqueada sin embargo tengo los dos problemas:

1. No me ocupa toda la pantalla
2. El UIImageview se puede manipular(Es decir recorrer hacia abajo segun de desplaze el scrollview.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has de tener claro que la barra de arriba es la `UINavigationBar` de un `UINavigationController` y que como tal, no es el `UIViewController` donde estás añadiendo la imagen. O dicho de otra forma, no estás añadiendo el `UIImageView` al `UINavigationController` y por esa razón no te ocupa la pantalla.
Has de tener claro que el `UINavigationController` es un contenedor que tiene implementada una cola con los `viewControllers` que vayas añadiendo y quitando. En tu caso, estás añadiendo la imagen en el `UIViewController` que está visible en ese momento en el `UINavigationController`.

Para que funcione correctamente, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Añadimos imagen
let dynamicImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
dynamicImage.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
navigationController?.view.addSubview(dynamicImage)

// Ocultamos imagen
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 10.0, options: [], animations: {

    dynamicImage.alpha = 0.0

}) { (completed) in

    dynamicImage.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Comment: Tienes razon!!! no me habia percatado de ese detalle. :) gracias @mhergon